# TWRPをビルドする際「Invalid variant: p1.」と出てエラーで止まる

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

私は自分でx96q allwinner h313のTWRPを作ろうとしています。
ファイルはすべてそろっていると思うのですが、下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
root@Owner:/home/TWRP# export ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true;
. build/envsetup.sh;
lunch omni_eros-p1-eng;
including device/google/eros-p1/vendorsetup.sh
device/google/eros-p1/vendorsetup.sh:8: add_lunch_combo is obsolete. Use COMMON_LUNCH_CHOICES in your AndroidProducts.mk instead.
device/google/eros-p1/vendorsetup.sh:9: add_lunch_combo is obsolete. Use COMMON_LUNCH_CHOICES in your AndroidProducts.mk instead.
device/google/eros-p1/vendorsetup.sh:10: add_lunch_combo is obsolete. Use COMMON_LUNCH_CHOICES in your AndroidProducts.mk instead.
[W][2023-12-02T19:55:04+0900][3130] void cmdline::logParams(nsjconf_t *)():250 Process will be UID/EUID=0 in the global user namespace, and will have user root-level access to files
[W][2023-12-02T19:55:04+0900][3130] void cmdline::logParams(nsjconf_t *)():260 Process will be GID/EGID=0 in the global user namespace, and will have group root-level access to files
In file included from build/make/core/config.mk:313:
In file included from build/make/core/envsetup.mk:312:
device/google/eros-p1/AndroidProducts.mk:11: error: device/google/eros-p1: omni_eros-p1-user: Invalid variant: p1.
19:55:04 dumpvars failed with: exit status 1
Device eros not found. Attempting to retrieve device repository from TeamWin Github (http://github.com/TeamWin).
Repository for eros not found in the TeamWin Github repository list.
If this is in error, you may need to manually add it to your .repo/local_manifests/roomservice.xml
[W][2023-12-02T19:55:05+0900][3192] void cmdline::logParams(nsjconf_t *)():250 Process will be UID/EUID=0 in the global user namespace, and will have user root-level access to files
[W][2023-12-02T19:55:05+0900][3192] void cmdline::logParams(nsjconf_t *)():260 Process will be GID/EGID=0 in the global user namespace, and will have group root-level access to files
In file included from build/make/core/config.mk:313:
In file included from build/make/core/envsetup.mk:312:
device/google/eros-p1/AndroidProducts.mk:11: error: device/google/eros-p1: omni_eros-p1-user: Invalid variant: p1.
19:55:05 dumpvars failed with: exit status 1
[W][2023-12-02T19:55:06+0900][3257] void cmdline::logParams(nsjconf_t *)():250 Process will be UID/EUID=0 in the global user namespace, and will have user root-level access to files
[W][2023-12-02T19:55:06+0900][3257] void cmdline::logParams(nsjconf_t *)():260 Process will be GID/EGID=0 in the global user namespace, and will have group root-level access to files
build/make/core/version_defaults.mk:56: warning: Invalid TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION 'eng', must be one of
In file included from build/make/core/config.mk:313:
In file included from build/make/core/envsetup.mk:68:
build/make/core/version_defaults.mk:57: error: SP2A.
19:55:06 dumpvars failed with: exit status 1

** Don't have a product spec for: 'omni_eros'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?
```